# Upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 crash

Tags: upgrade, crash

So last night I decided to upgrade my primary workstation from 15.04 to 15.10 via software updater and it just stopped with some errors about desktop wallpapers.

After about 30 minutes I just switched the PC off and went to sleep.

[image: Upgrade]

Answer (score 1):

This morning I booted the PC and it booted with one of my screens not working. Under the about Ubuntu it said 15.10.

I did a apt-get dist-upgrade and received errors about the software centre that has issues and some errors that I cant remember.

After some research I found that apparently there is also a bug in the distribution script which does not upgrade the kernel to 4.2 as well.

I started by apt-get -f install to fix issues with software centre. Rebooted and then apt-get clean and apt-get update. After this apt-get install linux-generic to upgrade the kernel. Rebooted and then apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade again to check if all is up to date and working. And yes it was.

Hope this info helps with similar issues.